# Sub-layout for the nested elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, sketchapp

Is there a way to show a layout for the nested element? I know it is possible to show the layout for whole `artboard`, but I can not found a way to show the layout for a specific rectangle.
For example, I make up html with `Bootstrap` and I have the following page:

```
<aside class="col-md-3"></aside>
<main class="col-md-6 article">
   <div class="col-md-9">Title</div>
   <div class="col-md-3">Author</div>
   <div class="col-md-12">Body</div>
</main>
<aside class="col-md-3"></aside>
```

In this example, I have a sub-layout for `.article` block. Is it possible to somehow show the sub layout for this block in `sketch app`?